# JAVA: Interrupt Thread after so much time has passed

Tags: java, multithreading, time, wsdl

I am currently working on a project that calls me to download a WSDL file from the internet.

Everything outside of my problem works great however...

I use the following code:

```
private Definition getDefinition(String url) throws WSDLException {

    // Read the url and return an instance to a WSDL Definition
    return WSDLFactory.newInstance().newWSDLReader().readWSDL(url);

}
```

This WSDLFactory is a Thread(to my knowledge).  The issue I have is that in the list of URL's I provide, a few of them point to WSDL's that no longer exist.  This in turn causes my program to wait an Extraordinarily long time before it realizes that it should throw a FileNotFoundException.  This is caused because the location the WSDL should be at takes forever to return an HTTP_RESPONSE code.

Is there a way I can wrap this WSDLFactory into something that attempts to get the WSDL but only gives it 5-10 seconds to do so?  After which, it says "You have had too much time to do this. We are stepping over you"?

Comment: Can you not simply remove the non-existent resources from the list?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Executor and Futures frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the underlying socket's timeout if possible `socket.setSoTimeout` or via a higher-level config option in the library.

Otheriwise (and if you've got Google's guava on the classpath) try:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html

Comment: I looked over this option and it looks promising however I am unable to get it to run. I am unable to find any working examples online.  Have you worked with this code before?  Would you be able to provide a short example implementing a TimeLimiter?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation class (link at end of comment).  You can use either `callWithTimeout` on a `Callable` or you can create a proxy. http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the http timeout `sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout`.  Of course this depends on the implementation of WSDLReader
Check here: 
[networking properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use a secondary thread, that calls the interrupt() method on the first thread after 5 seconds. Handle the InterruptedException in the first thread.